# Shortcuts: Sort pictures before handing them to Shortcut to make GIF (iOS / macOS)

Tags: macos, ios, sharing, shortcuts-app, animation

I am using Shortcuts to make GIFs from the sharing menu - which works really great!

Sadly I am not able to define in which order the images will be compiled to the GIF.

Is there a way? I haven't found anything ...neither on the web or in the Shortcuts command sets.

Would be really grateful if there was a solution for this!

Cheers!

Comment: Have you checked to see if it is organizing them in alphabetical order? That may be a solution.

Comment: Well, that's not a solution. Renaming takes too long. I will investigate further.